# accessing first element of a list to do conditional processing

Tags: scala

the below query does not work as i m trying to have a match statement within list iteration.
Need to access the first element of the list , so that i can pass a different condition.

```
  val alist= List(("a1","a2") ,("c1","c2") ,(null,null))
  val input = (null,null)

  val responseList = input match {
    case (null, null) => alist.map(t=> {  x  match {case alist.head => methodA(t)
                                                      case _ =>        methodB() })
    case _=>   methodB()}


  def methodA(t:(String,String)): Unit ={
    print (s"method A : ${t}")
  }

  def methodB(): Unit ={
    print ("method B")
  }
```

Comment: `methodA(alist.head) :: alist.tail(methodB)` (I am assuming the functions don't actually return `Unit`, and `methodB` actually takes parameters, it doesn't make very much sense otherwise)

Comment: methodA(alist.head) :: alist.tail(methodB) . Will :: operator does the work ?

Comment: yes MethodA and method B does other things. I have used Unit just for example purposes.

Comment: re. "will operator work?" ... What do you think? ;)

Comment: you are guru :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  val input = (null,null)

  val responseList = input match {
    case (null, null) => {  for ((tup,i) <- alist.zipWithIndex ) {methodA(i,tup)}   }
    case _=>   methodB()}
  
  def methodA(i:Int, t:(String,String)): Unit ={
    if (i==0) {println("First Element") }
    println (s"index $i , method A : ${t}")
  }

  def methodB(): Unit ={
    print ("method B")
  }
```

Need something more elegant

Comment: responseList doest matter. What i am trying to achieve is  run methodA for every tuple in the list . but process  the first tuple little differently.